# How to read multiple objects from text file using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, file-handling

I have a text file, which contains multiple objects written to it. I need to `fetch` all the objects as `JSON` in the text file. What should I do?

data in my file:

```
{"events":[...] },{"events":[....]},{},{}....
```

I tried to read it as :

```
fs.readFile('gcyoi6.txt', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    data =data.toString(); 
    console.log(data)
  });
```

it gives the data as a string. But I need it as `JSON` objects

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `const obj = JSON.parse( jsonString );`

Comment: @ippi SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the data which you get in the file to `JSON.parse` function which will converte string get from file into a JSON representation of the content which  is in your `.txt` file.

```
fs.readFile('gcyoi6.txt', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    data =JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data)
});
```

This is a valid text which can convert to JSON

```js
const validJSONString = JSON.parse(`[{"event":"name"},{"event": "test"}]`);

console.log(validJSONString);
```

This is a bad JSON

```js
const invalidJSONString = JSON.parse(`[{"event":"name"},{'event': 'test'}]`); // Throw an error error
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON

Comment: You should check that the content of your `.txt` file is properfly formated as JSON, by that I means you should use double quote arround String not single quote

Comment: i think , you weren't noticed the content in my file .They are not inside the array !

Comment: @gomathi_meena Well put them in an array instead of having broken JSON? Or if you really can't change the file format, `JSON.parse("[" + data + "]")`

Comment: By seeing the shape of content you provide as example in your question `{"events":[...] },{"events":[....]},{},{}....`. I presume your `.txt` file contain list of *Events* `Object` which  as some shape. So like it a list they should be wrap in a bracket or you can use some code to separate theme by using `String.prototype.split` methode which will return an `Array` of txt and you can passed that to `JSON.parse`

Comment: @YvesKipondo yes i did that  by enclosing square brackets with data, but thank you for your timely help !!!